# Are unvested contributions from the employer counted towards the 401K contribution limits?

Tags: united-states, 401k

I believe the annual total 401K contribution limits is $55000 (employee + employer + after-tax). Do the unvested contribution from the employer count towards this limit?

Comment: Yes they count, and you are correct on the amount for 2018.

Answer (score 5):

Yes they count, and you are correct on the amount for 2018.

[Reference](https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/irs-announces-2018-pension-plan-limitations-401k-contribution-limit-increases-to-18500-for-2018)